# Seeing error when creating legend for ggplot2: "Error: `stat` must be either a string or a Stat object, not an S3 object with class uneval"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish I could add a reproducible example, but I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'd like to plot an overlay of two histograms by the factor variable `localplus` which has 0/1 values (which I did no problem). But when I try to add a legend I get the error message:

```
Error: stat must be either a string or a Stat object, not an S3 object with class uneval
```

Here's my code:

```
ggplot(clmdata, aes(x=derv_alw_amt, fill=localplus)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), data=subset(clmdata, localplus == 1), aes(fill=localplus), binwidth = 10, fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), data=subset(clmdata, localplus == 0), aes(fill=localplus), binwidth = 10, fill = "green", alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 250, 10), lim=c(0,250), expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1L), breaks = seq(0, .25, .05), lim=c(0,.25), expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  ylab("Percent") +
  scale_fill_manual(name="localplus", values=c("blue","green"), labels=c("1","0"))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on without any associated data snippet, but it seems unnecessary to me to do two histogram layers. What happens when you only use one and leave out the `data = subset(...)` bit?

Comment: @teunbrand If I remove the two `geom_histogram` and replace with a single `geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), fill=localplus, binwidth = 10, alpha = 0.2)` I get the error message: `Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomBar,  :  object 'localplus' not found`.

Comment: Specifying data outside the `aes()` statement doesn't know to look for the variable in the provided data. I would remove the `fill = localplus` in your histogram line, since you've already specified it in the `ggplot(...)` line.

Comment: @teunbrand Thanks very much, I removed the `fill=localplus` from the histogram line, and also simplified the last line to  `scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue","green"))`, and hooray I'm seeing the legend now. However I do need to fix the frequency % on my y-axis so that the percentages are by group.

Comment: Try using `geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density)), ...)`, replace `after_stat()` by `stat()` if you have ggplot2 version <3.3.0.

Comment: @teunbrand Thanks, I'll give that a try!